# I can't find a regex to get '(% number%)' in string with php

Tags: regex

I can't find a regex to get '(% number%)' in string.
For example I would like to get `(100), (2000) ...` inside the following string:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text (100) of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the (2000) industry's standard dummy
> text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
> type and scrambled it to (40) make a type specimen book. It has
> survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
> typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularized in
> the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
> passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
> Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: You can get the numbers inside of parenthesis with `(\(\d+\))` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RpDmNc/1/)

Comment: Thank you @dawg